# Enable multiproc in Msbuild via API

Tags: msbuild, multicore

With Msbuild v3.5 I can include [the "/m" switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx) to enable multiprocessor support . However I cannot find an equivalent property that hangs off of anything in [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.aspx). How do I enable this setting via the API?

I tried to discover this myself by reflecting over Msbuild.exe (thanks Lutz!) but it doesn't use the BuildEngine instead using System.Threading.Thread directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this...

http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2007/10/22/enabling-multiprocessor-support-in-an-msbuild-host.aspx

... answer your question?

Essentially, it looks as if you use the constructor of Engine that takes a parameter for the number of CPUs to use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300140.aspx

```
public Engine(
    BuildPropertyGroup globalProperties,
    ToolsetDefinitionLocations locations,
    int numberOfCpus,
    string localNodeProviderParameters
)
```